# Searching Scrabble dictionary for word with a blank tile (" ") character

Tags: java, regex, string, hashset

Let's say I have a `String` called `s` that represents a move on a Scrabble board: `"AARDV RK"`

I have a `HashSet<String>` called `dict` that contains the entire Scrabble Dictionary (~180,000 words!).

How could I use regular expressions to search `dict` for `s`, but where the whitespace character represents any  uppercase letter?

Comment: What expression did you come up with so far?

Comment: No. Regex does not work with HashSet. That, or you have to loop through the whole dictionary and use regex to check each of the string. This is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
^AARDV[A-Z]RK$
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the dictionaly doesn't contain anything else but uppercase letters, the simplest option will be the best:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("AARDV.RK")`
for (String entry : dict)
  if (p.matcher(entry).matches()) return entry;
return null;
```

The wildcard `.` will match any character at that position, which will save you the slight penalty of making any kind of redundant check on this character. Note also that it is very important to compile the regex upfront and not recompile it again for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Instead of looking for a random letter, you could just look for all words which would fit the players current tray of tiles.

Consider the following powershell example of a regex and Logic. Here I'm using logic to construct a regex based on the tiles the player currently has. The resulting regex has two distinct parts a match for between 1 and the total number of each letter in the player's tray, and the second part matches between 0 and +1 of each letter in the player's tray. So the player has 2 `A`'s in their tray the regex would attempt to match between 0 and 3 `A`'s while still requiring 1 to the total number of each letter for all the other letters. This process iterates for each of the letters.

So given your example. If a player has `aarvfrk` in their tray, the regex would look for all words with all the letters like `aardvark` but `aardvarks` would match too, however we eliminate that later by filtering out the matches based on word length `where {$_.Length -le $($PlayerTiles.Length + 1)}`. So a word can't have more then 2 extra tiles then exist in the players tray.

Next I construct a regex which to look for letters in the found words which the player doesn't currently have in their tray.

Granted there are edge cases where this particular logic may fail, like if the player is missing two letters to spell the word. Knowing these words might help in rare cases where a given board layout might have the letter you're looking for. You could solve this by evaluating the board layout and include all single letters on the board as if they were part of the player's tray. This evaluation would need to be smart enough to identify letters which couldn't be used due to board layout. It could also be made smart enough to identify multiple character strings from the board layout which would be legal to use. But all that is beyond the scope of your original question.

## Notes

Depending on your choice of language you may need to replace the `*?` in any of the lookbehinds with something like `{0,100}`. This is due to how the language [**like java**] implements it's lookbehinds where the searching for string can be an undetermined size.

## Source Code

```
    $Matches = @()
    [array]$Dictionary = @()

    $Dictionary += 'AARDVARK'
    $Dictionary += 'AARDVRKS'
    $Dictionary += 'AARDVARKS'
    $Dictionary += 'ANTHILL'
    $Dictionary += 'JUMPING'
    $Dictionary += 'HILLSIDE'
    $Dictionary += 'KITTENS'
    $Dictionary += 'LOVER'
    $Dictionary += 'LOVE'
    $Dictionary += 'LOVES'
    $Dictionary += 'LOVELY'
    $Dictionary += 'OLIVE'
    $Dictionary += 'VOTE'


    $PlayerTiles = "aardvrk"

Function funBuildRegexForPlayerTiles ([string]$GivenTiles) {

    # split the GivenTiles so each letter is seperate, and store these in a hashtable so the letter is the keyname and the number times it's seen is the value, This deduplicates each letter
    [hashtable]$SearchForTiles = @{}
    foreach ($Letter in $GivenTiles[0..$($GivenTiles.Length - 1)] ) {
        $SearchForTiles[$Letter] += 1
        } # next letter

    # build regex for tiles to match just the tiles we have 
    [string]$SameNumberRegex = ""
    foreach ($Letter in $SearchForTiles.Keys) {
        $SameNumberRegex += "(?=^([^$Letter]*?$Letter){1,$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])}(?![^$Letter]*?$Letter))"
        } # next letter


    # add to the regex to include one extra letter of each type. 
    [array]$ExtraLetterRegex = @()
    foreach ($MasterLetter in $SearchForTiles.Keys) {
        [string]$TempRegex = ""
        foreach ($Letter in $SearchForTiles.Keys) {
            if ($MasterLetter -ieq $Letter) {
                # this forces each letter to allow zero to one extra of itself in the dictionary string. This allows us to match words which would have all the other letters and none of this letter
                $TempRegex += "(?=^([^$Letter]*?$Letter){0,$($SearchForTiles[$Letter] + 1)}(?![^$Letter]*?$Letter))"

                } else {
                # All the rest of these tiles on this regex section will need to have just the number of tiles the player has
                $TempRegex += "(?=^([^$Letter]*?$Letter){1,$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])}(?![^$Letter]*?$Letter))"
                } # end if
            } # next letter
        $ExtraLetterRegex += $TempRegex

        Write-Host "To match an extra '$MasterLetter': " $TempRegex
        } # next MasterLetter

    # put it all together
    [array]$AllRegexs = @()
    $AllRegexs += $SameNumberRegex
    $AllRegexs += $ExtraLetterRegex


    # stitch all the regexs together to make a massive regex 
    [string]$Output = $AllRegexs -join "|"

    return $Output
    } # end function funBuildRegexForPlayerTiles        


Function funBuildMissingLetterRegex ([string]$GivenTiles) {
    # split the GivenTiles so each letter is seperate, and store these in a hashtable so the letter is the keyname and the number times it's seen is the value, This deduplicates each letter
    [hashtable]$SearchForTiles = @{}
    foreach ($Letter in $GivenTiles[0..$($GivenTiles.Length - 1)] ) {
        $SearchForTiles[$Letter] += 1
        } # next letter

    [array]$MissingLetterRegex = @()
    # include any letters which do not match the current tiles
    $MissingLetterRegex += "(?i)([^$($SearchForTiles.Keys -join '')])"

    # build the regex to find the missing tiles
    foreach ($Letter in $SearchForTiles.Keys) {
        $MissingLetterRegex += "(?i)(?<=($Letter[^$Letter]*?){$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])})($Letter)"
        } # next letter

    [string]$Output = $MissingLetterRegex -join "|"
    return $Output
    } # end function


    [string]$Regex = funBuildRegexForPlayerTiles -GivenTiles $PlayerTiles
    Write-Host "Player tiles '$PlayerTiles'"
    Write-Host "Regex = '$Regex'"
    Write-Host "Matching words = "  
    $MatchedWords = $Dictionary -imatch $Regex | where {$_.Length -le $($PlayerTiles.Length + 1)}

    [string]$MissingLetterRegex = funBuildMissingLetterRegex $PlayerTiles
    foreach ($Word in $MatchedWords) {
        Write-Host $Word -NoNewline
        # find all the letters for which the player doesn't have a matching tile
        [array]$MissingTiles = ([regex]"$MissingLetterRegex").matches($Word) | foreach {
            Write-Output $_.Groups[0].Value
            } # next match
        Write-Host "`tLetters you are missing to spell this work '$($MissingTiles -join '')'"
        } # next word

    Write-Host -------------------------------

    $PlayerTiles = "OLLVE"
    [hashtable]$SearchForTiles = @{}

    # build regex for tiles
    [string]$Regex = funBuildRegexForPlayerTiles -GivenTiles $PlayerTiles


    Write-Host "Player tiles '$PlayerTiles'"
    Write-Host "Regex = '$Regex'"
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Matching words = "  
    $MatchedWords = $Dictionary -imatch $Regex | where {$_.Length -le $($PlayerTiles.Length + 1)}

    [string]$MissingLetterRegex = funBuildMissingLetterRegex $PlayerTiles
    foreach ($Word in $MatchedWords) {
        Write-Host $Word -NoNewline
        # find all the letters for which the player doesn't have a matching tile
        [array]$MissingTiles = ([regex]"$MissingLetterRegex").matches($Word) | foreach {
            Write-Output $_.Groups[0].Value
            } # next match
        Write-Host "`tLetters you are missing to spell this work '$($MissingTiles -join '')'"
        } # next word
```

## Yields

```
To match an extra 'r':  (?=^([^r]*?r){0,3}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))
To match an extra 'v':  (?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){0,2}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))
To match an extra 'a':  (?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){0,3}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))
To match an extra 'k':  (?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){0,2}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))
To match an extra 'd':  (?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){0,2}(?![^d]*?d))
Player tiles 'aardvrk'
Regex = '(?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))|(?=^([^r]*?r){0,3}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))|(?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){0,2}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))|(?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){0,3}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))|(?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){0,2}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){1,1}(?![^d]*?d))|(?=^([^r]*?r){1,2}(?![^r]*?r))(?=^([^v]*?v){1,1}(?![^v]*?v))(?=^([^a]*?a){1,2}(?![^a]*?a))(?=^([^k]*?k){1,1}(?![^k]*?k))(?=^([^d]*?d){0,2}(?![^d]*?d))'
Matching words = 
AARDVARK    Letters you are missing to spell this work 'A'
AARDVRKS    Letters you are missing to spell this work 'S'
-------------------------------
To match an extra 'O':  (?=^([^O]*?O){0,2}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))
To match an extra 'E':  (?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){0,2}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))
To match an extra 'L':  (?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){0,3}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))
To match an extra 'V':  (?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){0,2}(?![^V]*?V))
Player tiles 'OLLVE'
Regex = '(?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))|(?=^([^O]*?O){0,2}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))|(?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){0,2}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))|(?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){0,3}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){1,1}(?![^V]*?V))|(?=^([^O]*?O){1,1}(?![^O]*?O))(?=^([^E]*?E){1,1}(?![^E]*?E))(?=^([^L]*?L){1,2}(?![^L]*?L))(?=^([^V]*?V){0,2}(?![^V]*?V))'

Matching words = 
LOVER   Letters you are missing to spell this work 'R'
LOVE    Letters you are missing to spell this work ''
LOVES   Letters you are missing to spell this work 'S'
LOVELY  Letters you are missing to spell this work 'Y'
OLIVE   Letters you are missing to spell this work 'I'
VOTE    Letters you are missing to spell this work 'T'
```

## Summary

The first part where we are looking for matching words I'm using a regex made up these chunks: `(?=^([^$Letter]*?$Letter){1,$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])}(?![^$Letter]*?$Letter))`. All these chunks are seperated by `|` or statements.

- `(?=` start zero width assertion

  - `^` match beginning of the string
  - `(` create a group of required character sequences
  - `[^$Letter]*?` match any character but the letter we're looking for zero or more times non-greedy
  - `$Letter` match the letter
  - `)` close the group
- `{` force the group to happen

  - `1` at least one time
  - `,` and
  - `$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])` upto the total number of this tile a the player has
  - `}` end the quantity check
- `(?!` use look around to prevent any

  - `[^$Letter]*?` any number of the characters which are not this letter
  - `$Letter` followed by this letter
  - `)` end of the look around
- `)` end of this zero width assertion essentially the end of looking for this letter

When search for the missing letters in a word I'm using `(?i)([^$($SearchForTiles.Keys -join '')])` followed by these chunks for each letter `(?i)(?<=($Letter[^$Letter]*?){$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])})($Letter)`. All these chucks are separated by `|` or statements

- `(?i)` enforce case nonsensitive

  - `(` start group check
  - `[^` not including these characters
  - `$($SearchForTiles.Keys -join '')` take each of the de-duplicated letters in the players tile set and join them together
  - `]` end of the character set
  - `)` that essentially returns all the letters which are not in the player's tray
- `|` the or statement
- followed by one group like this for each letter in the player's tray
- `(?i)` force case nonsensitive
- `(?<=` start lookbehind
- `(` start group of characters which must be in this order

  - `$Letter` look for this letter
  - `[^$Letter]` followed by any character which is not this letter
  - `*?` zero or more times
  - `)` close the group of characters which must be in this order
  - `{$($SearchForTiles[$Letter])}` that group must exist at least once for each tile in the player's trya before we start matching missing letter
  - `)` close the lookbehind
- `($Letter)` match the letter we're looking for, if this matches then the player is missing this letter in their tray so this letter will be returned.

Comment: I would probably deal with the wild card by increasing the filter which limits the length of the each matching word by +1 character for each wild card token in the players tray. And not attempt to include the wild card in the regex.  Of course the second part of the logic would need to be updated to allow for the wildcard.